# Change Laravel config settings from the front end?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.0. I need to be able to change the value of the session lifetime in  `config/session.php` from the front end, making the value configurable to an admin user of my site.

In the docs I've read that you can get/set variables using the config helper function, like so:

```
    config(['session.lifetime' => '60']);

    config('session.lifetime'); // '60'
```

But it it only changes the configuration value for that request. How do I persist this configuration, making it work across all requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend implementing a custom session driver that reads the lifetime value out of the database.

It is pretty easy and you'll only have to override the GC (garbage collection) method, as well as creating a database table to store this value.

I've done it in the past to make soft-deleting database sessions for analytics purposes. Let me know if you need any code snippets to proceed.

Edit: with code, my problem was slightly different, so I have edited in some key components but this doesn't pretend to be a complete solution:

I created a folder called `Library\Session` under app to store this new `SessionHandler` in:

```
<?php

namespace App\Library\Session;

use DB;

class DynamicallyConfiguredDatabaseSessionHandler extends \Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function read($sessionId)
    {
        $session = (object) $this->getQuery()->find($sessionId);

        if (isset($session->payload)) {
            $this->exists = true;

            return base64_decode($session->payload);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function write($sessionId, $data)
    {
        if ($this->exists) {
            $this->getQuery()->where('id', $sessionId)->update([
                'payload' => base64_encode($data), 'last_activity' => time(),
            ]);
        } else {
            $this->getQuery()->insert([
                'id' => $sessionId, 'payload' => base64_encode($data), 'last_activity' => time()
            ]);
        }

        $this->exists = true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function destroy($sessionId)
    {
        $this->getQuery()->where('id', $sessionId)->delete();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function gc($lifetime)
    {
        $dynamic_lifetime = DB::select('select lifetime from config limit 1');
        $this->getQuery()->where('last_activity', '<=', time() - $dynamic_lifetime)->delete();
    }

}
```

Then in `config/session.php` set `'driver' => 'dynamically_configured_database'`

Then in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` use this `boot()` method:

```
public function boot()
{   
    //This is seriously the only way to modify how sessions work
    \Session::extend('dynamically_configured_database', function() {
        $connection = $this->app['config']['session.connection'];

        $connection = $this->app['db']->connection($connection);
        $table = $this->app['config']['session.table'];

        return new \App\Library\Session\DynamicallyConfiguredDatabaseSessionHandler($connection, $table);
    }); 
}
```

To ensure that the session is destroyed at the end of the specified period every time, change the garbage collection lottery odds in `session.php` like so:

`'lottery' => [1, 1],`

Prepare for this to take a little time, and I would love to hear your lessons learned about easier ways to add in custom database drivers, but once I got it working it hasn't had any problems yet.

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you could post a some code snippets, this method sounds promising.

Comment: @TimothyBuktu ended up adding more or less everything I have on this. If you're using file based sessions you'll just have to modify the logic to use file age or whatever instead of `last_activity`, take a look at how the existing SessionHandlers are implemented, they should give you a pretty good idea of what works.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the help. There was something else I had to do, but I'll add it your answer

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't even think about the lottery, definitely needed to guarantee the garbage collection is fired in time.

Answer (score 2):

This answer may be dumb, try to session flash an object that has the changes. Then implant a middleware that takes what is flashed in session and redo the config changes, then reflash.

```
$whatever_to_change = ['session.lifetime' => '60'];
session()->flash('changes', $whatever_to_change);
config($whatever_to_change);
```

In a middleware:

```
$from_flash = session()->get('changes');
config($whatever_to_change);
session()->keep(['changes']);
```

Then use this middleware in your other routes. I think this may not work if you want to change session driver.

Comment: Although this would change the config setting on every page as it loads, I don't think it would have the desired effect of actually changing and persisting the session lifetime. Might be useful in other situations though